# Laravel language switcher, pass additional parameters to a route

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-blade

I really can't think of an elegant solution to fix this problem so here it is:

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqzGKg8IxE4 to create a localization option for my website. However, integrating the auth was cancer and now I'm faced with an even greater issue regarding the routing for pages that require a get parameter.

Here is my blade code inside the app.blade.php for the language switcher:

```
                            <language-switcher
                                locale="{{ app()->getLocale() }}"
                                link-en="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}"
                                link-bg="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'bg') }}"
                            ></language-switcher>
```

And here are some of my routes

```
Route::redirect('/', '/en');

Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');


Route::group([
    "prefix" => '{language}',
    'where' => ['language' => '(en||bg)'],
], function () {

    //Auth routes
    Auth::routes();

    //Returns to home
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    //Handles the faq routes
    Route::resource('faq', 'FaqController');

});


Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');

});
```

It works well for pages that don't require any get parameters to work with ex: Login / Register / Home page, however if i use something that requires like, faq.edit, which takes an {id} parameters - the language switcher will throw an error because I haven't passed an {id} parameter to it.

The only solution I can think of is adding the language-switcher inside the child blade view and from there I pass the required parameters, however that implies that I have to add the language-switcher to every child view instead of only once at the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with the following steps:

- Implement a URL generator macro which will make much easier to generate your URLs which must be identical except language
- Get the current route's parameters
- Merge the chosen language into them

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        UrlGenerator::macro('toLanguage', function (string $language) {
            $currentRoute = app('router')->current();
            $newRouteParameters = array_merge(
                $currentRoute->parameters(), compact('language')
            );
            return $this->route($currentRoute->getName(), $newRouteParameters);
        });
    }
}
```

And in your Blade file

```html
@inject('app', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application')
@inject('urlGenerator', 'Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator')

<language-switcher
    locale="{{ $app->getLocale() }}"
    link-en="{{ $urlGenerator->toLanguage('en') }}"
    link-bg="{{ $urlGenerator->toLanguage('bg') }}"
></language-switcher>
```

You'll notice I used contracts injection instead of using facades. More informations here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/contracts#contracts-vs-facades

And if you don't known Laravel macros, more informations here https://tighten.co/blog/the-magic-of-laravel-macros

Comment: That did it. Didn't even know you could create your own helpers inside laravel components, thanks for the help!